# Neural network gets only 50% good prediction on test data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I made a neural network whice i want to classify the input data (400 caracteristics per input data) as one of the five arabic dialects. I divede the trainig data in "train data", "validation data" and than "test date", with `net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';` . I use `trainbr` as training function, whice results in a long training, that's because i have 9000 elements in training data.
For the network arhitecture i used two-layers, first with 10 perceptrons, second with 5, 5 because i use one vs all strategy.
The network training ends usually with minimum gradient reached, rather than minimux error.

How can i make the network predict better? Could it be o problem with generalization (the network learn very well the training data, but test on new data tends to fail?
Should i add more perceptrons to the first layer? I'm asking that because i take about a hour to train the network when i have 10 perceptrons on  first layer, so the time will increase.

This is the code for my network:

```
[Test] = load('testData.mat');
[Ex] = load('trainData.mat');

Ex.trainVectors = Ex.trainVectors';
Ex.trainLabels = Ex.trainLabels';

net = newff(minmax(Ex.trainVectors),[10 5] ,{'logsig','logsig'},'trainlm','learngdm','sse');
net.performFcn = 'mse';
net.trainParam.lr = 0.01;
net.trainParam.mc = 0.95;
net.trainParam.epochs = 1000;
net.trainParam.goal = 0;
net.trainParam.max_fail = 50;

net.trainFcn = 'trainbr';   

net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 0.7;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 0.15;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0.15;

net = init(net);

net = train(net,Ex.trainVectors,Ex.trainLabels);
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with neural networks is some type of creative work. So noone can't give you the only true answer. But I can give some advices based on my own experience.

1. First of all - check the network error when training ends (on training and validation data sets. Before you start to use test data set). You told it is minimum but what is its actual value? If it 50% too, so we have bad data or wrong net architecture.
2. If error for train data set is OK. Next step - lets check how much the coefficients of your net are changing at the validation step. And what's up about the error here. If they changed dramatically that's the sigh our architecture is wrong: Network does not have the ability to generalize and will retrain at every new data sets.
3. What else can we do before changing architecture? We can change the number of epochs. Sometimes we can get good results but it is some type of random - we must be sure the changing of coefficient is small at the ending steps of training. But as I remember `nntool` check it automatically, so maybe we can skip this step.
4. One more thing I want to recommend to you - change train data set. Maybe you know `rand` is give you always the same number at start of matlab, so if you create your data sets only once you can work with the same sets always. This problem is also about non-homogeneous data. It can be that some part of your data is more important than other. So if some different random sets will give about the same error data is ok and we can go further. If not - we need to work with data and split it more carefully. Sometimes I avoid using `dividerand` and divide data manually.
5. Sometimes I tried to change the type of activation function. But here you use perceptron... So the idea - try to use sigma- or linear- neurons instead of perceptrons. This rarely leads to significant improvements but can help.
6. If all this steps can't give you enough you have to change net architecture. And the number of neurons in the first layer is the first you have to do. Usually when I work on the neural network I spend a lot of time trying not only different number of neurons but the different types of nets too. 
   For example, I found interesting **article** about your topic:  [link at Alberto Simões article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/17b2/c9ae27d2ef1b6b901a0afd5aa8649f7795bf.pdf). And that's what they say:

> Regarding the number of units in the hidden layers, there are some
>   rules of thumb: use the same number of units in all hidden layers, and
>   use at least the same number of units as the maximum between the
>   number of classes and the number of features. But there can be up to
>   three times that value. Given the high number of features we opted to
>   keep that same number of units in the hidden layer.

---

Some advices from comments:
Data split method (for train and test data sets) depends on your data. For example, I worked on industry data and found that at the last part of the data set technological parameters (pressure for some equipment) was changed. So I have to get data for both operation modes to train data set. But for your case I don't thing there are the same problem... I recommend you to try several random sets (just check they are really different!).

For measuring net error I usually calculate full vector of errors - I train net and then check it's work for all values to get the whole errors vector. It's useful to get some useful vies like histograms and etc and I can see where my net is go wrong. It is not necessary and even harmful to get sse (or mse) close to zero - usually that's mean you already overtrain the net. For the first approximation I usually try to get 80-95% of correct values on training data set and then try the net on the test data set.

Comment: @CalinCretu it depends on your data. For example, I worked on industry data and found that at the last part of the data set technological parameters (pressure for some equipment) was changed. So I have to get data for both operation modes to train data set. But for your case I don't thing there are the same problem... I recommend you to try several random sets (just check they are really different!).

Comment: i have another question, if you're kind : how can i interpret the error if I use SSE as error function. What value of sse should be fine (beacause training until 0 error value is reached, will for sure over-train my network). Or, what can i use to get a percent of well classification? Thanks very much

Comment: I checked my classification error on training data and it is about 50%.

Comment: @CalinCretu I usually calculate full vector of errors - I train net and then check it's work for all values to get the whole errors vector. It's useful to get some useful vies like histograms and etc and I can see where my net is go wrong. It is not necessary and even harmful to get sse close to zero - usually that's mean you already overtrain the net. For the first approximation I usually try to get 80-95% of correct values on training data set and then try the net on the test data set.

Comment: @CalinCretu 
If you get only 50% correct values on the training data set it is a bad result. Try my advices one by one. I suppose you need to change it's architecture.